# Return text from div when click some link from this div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need return text from div.
When I click on **Click me**, I want to alert with text  from `div class='show_mail_middle'`

```
<div class='show_mail'>
<div class='show_mail_top'><p class='cli'>click me</p></div>
<div class='show_mail_middle'>1</div>
</div>


<div class='show_mail'>
<div class='show_mail_top'><p class='cli'>click me</p></div>
<div class='show_mail_middle'>2</div>
</div>

<div class='show_mail'>
<div class='show_mail_top'><p class='cli'>click me</p></div>
<div class='show_mail_middle'>3</div>
</div>
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: Did you find any of the answers below useful?

Answer (score 1):

Use by Pure JavaScript.

```
var allDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('show_mail_top');
for(var i=0; i<allDiv.length; i++){
    allDiv[i].onclick = function (){
        alert(this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML);
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Yyd4/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on("click",".show_mail_top",function(){
    alert($(this).find("p").text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/MM7Gq/)

```
$('.cli').click(function () {
    alert($(this).closest('div').next().text());
});
```

---

or [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/MM7Gq/1)

```
$('.cli').click(function () {
    alert($(this).parent().next().text());
          //^get parent element div of current element with class .cli which 
//clicked and than find next div element n get it's text
});
```

---

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

[.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next)

[this keyword](https://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of [**.closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) & [**.next()**](http://api.jquery.com/next)

Use

```
$('.cli').click(function () {
    alert($(this).parent().next('.show_mail_middle').text());
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/28NjU/)

*OR*

```
$('.cli').click(function () {
    alert($(this).closest('.show_mail_top').next('.show_mail_middle').text());
});
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/6K7gW/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".show_mail_top").click(function() {
   $(this).parent().children(".show_mail_middle").text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('p.cli').click(function(){
   alert($('div.show_mail_middle').text())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/35HjS/)**

```
$('.cli').click(function() {

    var text = $(this).parents('.show_mail').find('.show_mail_middle').html();

     alert(text);
});
```